# How to read custom annotation value using reflection?

Tags: reflection, annotations

I am trying to read custom annotation value using reflection.

I see the custom annotation in debug but when i try to typecast annotation to my custom annotation, I am getting ClassCastException.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//custom annotation

@Retention(Retention.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface SendEmail{
public String id;
}


//method annotated with custom annotation

@SendEmail(id="test@test.com")
public void testEmail(){

}


// extracting custom annotation using reflection

Set<Method> annotatedMethods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(SendEmail.class);

for(Methods method : annotatedMethods){
  Annotations[] annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
  SendEmail sendEmail = method.getAnnotation(SendEmail.class); // returns null;

  for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    annotation.annotationType.getName(); // com.test.email.annotation.SendEmail
    annotation.toString(); // @com.test.email.annotation.SendEmail(id=test@test.com)
    SendEmail sendEmail = (SendEmail) annotation; // ClassCastException com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24 cannot be cast to com.test.email.annotation.SendEmail

    if(annotation.annotationType.getName() == SendEmail.class.getName()){
      SendEmail sendEmail = (SendEmail) annotation; // ClassCastException com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24 cannot be cast to com.test.email.annotation.SendEmail
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can read custom annotation value using java reflection as described in below code.

public class ValidatorClassName implements ConstraintValidator<RemarkValid, Object> {

```
private String remark;
private String enable;

@Override
public void initialize(RemarkValid constraintAnnotation) {
    enable = constraintAnnotation.enable();
    remark = constraintAnnotation.remark();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Object objectToValidate, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    String remarkFieldValue;
    Boolean enableFieldValue;
    try {
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        remarkFieldValue = (String) getFieldValue(objectToValidate, remark);
        enableFieldValue = (Boolean) getFieldValue(objectToValidate, enable);

        /*logic*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return true;
}

private Object getFieldValue(Object object, String remark) throws Exception {
    Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(remark);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field.get(object);
}
```

}

As well as can create a BeanWrapperImpl for the given object to read bean property value as below,

```
BeanWrapper objectToValidateBean = new BeanWrapperImpl(objectToValidate);
    Object actualValue = objectToValidateBean.getPropertyValue(remark);
```